# Passing More Than One Managed Metadata Term to a List Field Via a Webpart

Tags: web-part, managed-metadata, list-item

I have a Webpart that adds items to a list.
it has a managed metadata field that can get more than one term

but when I submit the data, the first one gets submitted and there is a semicolon after it

BTW the "Allow multiple value" is checked for that managed metadata column.

what should I change in my code to be able to submit more than one metadata field
here is the code:

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        int rowIndex = 0;
        List<string> Student = new List<string>();
        List<string> marks = new List<string>();
        List<string> StudentNotes = new List<string>();
        //MessageLabel.Text = "";
        var query1 = "";
        int flag = 0;
        string maximummarks = MaximumMarks_TextBox.Text;
        string[] split = TaxonomyWebTaggingControl2.Text.Split(new char[] { '|' });
        string examsubjectguid = split[1];
        string examsubject = split[0];
        split = TaxonomyWebTaggingControl1.Text.Split(new char[] { '|' });
        string examtypeguid = split[1];
        string examtype = split[0];
        split = TaxonomyWebTaggingControl3.Text.Split(new char[] { '|' });
        string examlevelguid = split[1];
        string examlevel = split[0];
        string examdate1 = examdate.SelectedDate.ToString("d");
        Status_Textbox.Text = examdate1;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {

            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values

                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label box1 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("Label2");
                    Student.Add(box1.Text);
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    int tempmarks = -1;
                    string currentMark = box2.Text.Trim();
                    marks.Add(currentMark);
                    //if (box1.Text == " ")
                    //{
                    //    tempmarks = -1;
                    //}
                    //else
                    //{
                    //    tempmarks = Convert.ToInt32(box2.Text);
                    //}
                    //marks.Add(tempmarks);

                    //if (tempmarks > Convert.ToInt32(maximummarks.ToString()))
                    //{
                    //    MessageLabel.Text = "Please enter marks less than maximum marks";
                    //    flag = 1;
                    //}
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox3");
                    StudentNotes.Add((box3.Text));


                    string a = "Item " + i + " -" + box1.Text + " , " + box2.Text + " , " + box3.Text;
                    query1 += a.ToString();


                    rowIndex++;

                }


            }

            if (flag == 1)
            {
                //MessageLabel.Text = query1 + "exam subject -" + examsubject + " examtype -" + examtype + " examlevel -" + examlevel + " Exam Date" + examdate + " Maximum Marks" + maximummarks;
            }
            else
            {
                using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        // Fetch the List
                        SPList list = oSPWeb.Lists[SCORE_LISTNAME]; //name of score list

                        //Add a new item in the score List 

                        try
                        {
                            if (Student.Count > 0)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < Student.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(marks[i].ToString()))
                                    {


                                    SPListItem itemToAdd = list.Items.Add();


                                    // itemToAdd["Title"] = "Item" + i;
                                    int studid = GetLookupIDFromList(oSPWeb, "دانش‌آموزان", "_x0646__x0627__x0645__x0020__x06", Student[i]);
                                    //Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Studid \n" + studid + " .');</script>");
                                    SPFieldLookupValue lv = new SPFieldLookupValue(studid, Student[i]);
                                    // lv.LookupValue = Student[i];

                                    itemToAdd[SCORE_LISTNAME_FIELD_STUDENTFAMILY] = lv;//Student[i]; //internastudent family column name from score
                                   //added by sajid
                                  //  Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Mark Obtain \n" + marks[i] + " .');</script>");
                                    if (marks[i].ToString() == "غ")
                                    {
                                        itemToAdd[SCORE_LISTNAME_FIELD_ABSENCE] = true;
                                        //itemToAdd[SCORE_LISTNAME_FIELD_MARKS] = 0; //Convert.ToInt32(marks[i]); //marks column from score
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        itemToAdd[SCORE_LISTNAME_FIELD_MARKS] = Convert.ToInt32(marks[i]); //marks column from score
                                    }
                                    //end
                                    itemToAdd[SCORE_LISTNAME_FIELD_MAXIMUM_MARKS] = maximummarks; //maximum marks 
                                    itemToAdd[SCORE_LISTNAME_FIELD_EXAMDATE] = examdate.SelectedDate;//exam date
                                    itemToAdd[SCORE_LISTNAME_FIELD_NOTES] = StudentNotes[i];

                                    var managedMetaDataField = list.Fields[TERMSET_EXAMTYPE_NAME] as TaxonomyField;
                                    var termsetId = managedMetaDataField.TermSetId;
                                    var termstoreId = managedMetaDataField.SspId;
                                    var taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(oSPWeb.Site);
                                    var termstore = taxonomySession.TermStores[termstoreId];
                                    var termset = termstore.GetTermSet(termsetId);
                                    var termname = examtype;
                                    var terms = termset.GetTerms(termname, false);
                                    Term term;
                                    term = terms[0];

                                    managedMetaDataField.SetFieldValue(itemToAdd, term);
                                    managedMetaDataField = list.Fields[TERMSET_EXAMSUBJECT_NAME] as TaxonomyField;
                                    termsetId = managedMetaDataField.TermSetId;
                                    termstoreId = managedMetaDataField.SspId;
                                    //taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(oSPWeb.Site);
                                    termstore = taxonomySession.TermStores[termstoreId];
                                    termset = termstore.GetTermSet(termsetId);
                                    termname = examsubject;
                                    terms = termset.GetTerms(termname, false);
                                    //Term term;
                                    term = terms[0];

                                    managedMetaDataField.SetFieldValue(itemToAdd, term);
                                    managedMetaDataField = list.Fields[TERMSET_EXAM_LEVEL_NAME] as TaxonomyField;
                                    termsetId = managedMetaDataField.TermSetId;
                                    termstoreId = managedMetaDataField.SspId;
                                    //taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(oSPWeb.Site);
                                    termstore = taxonomySession.TermStores[termstoreId];
                                    termset = termstore.GetTermSet(termsetId);
                                    termname = examlevel;
                                    terms = termset.GetTerms(termname, false);
                                    //Term term;
                                    term = terms[0];

                                    managedMetaDataField.SetFieldValue(itemToAdd, term);
                                  //  itemToAdd.Update();
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(marks[i].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        itemToAdd.Update();
                                    }


                                }
                            }
                            }
                            //MessageLabel.Text = "Item  Updated successfully";
                            Status_Textbox.Text = "Item  Updated successfully";

                            DropDownList1.ClearSelection();
                            examdate.ClearSelection();
                            TaxonomyWebTaggingControl1.Text = " ";
                            TaxonomyWebTaggingControl2.Text = " ";
                            TaxonomyWebTaggingControl3.Text = " ";
                            MaximumMarks_TextBox.Text = " ";
                            GridView2.Visible = false;
                            // Response.Redirect("",true);

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //MessageLabel.Text = "Item Not Updated successfully" + ex.Message;
                            Status_Textbox.Text = "Item Not Updated successfully" + ex.Message;
                            //throw;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        }

                    }

                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using JavaScript? Can you share your code please.

Comment: no, it's not JavaScript. I added the code.